# how to check S.M.A.R.T., hdd performance etc, on VPS

Tags: server, hard-drive, performance, vps

There are a little bit problem.
On local machine (own), all works fine, but, since I moved my projects to VPS (you know, internet all the time, electricy backups and so on), I notified, that a lot of programs aren't work or aren't work properly.
I couldn't check SMART on my VPS

sudo apt-get install smartmontools
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda

results:
smartctl open device: /dev/sda failed: No such device

So, how can I check SMART and performance on VPS?

Comment: SMART works for physical disks. A VPS is a virtual server with a *virtual* hard drive. You should ask your hosting provider to do the checks for you. Most likely your VPS does not even run on a separate single hard drive, but in a storage cluster, so SMART checks will be done at that level and you should not even have to worry about this at all! Please ask a NEW, more specific question about the programs not working.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP is asking for something impossible; virtual hard drives don't provide SMART diagnostics, which is only useful and present on physical drives.

Comment: Okay, it's my bad, about VPS and SMART (still not get info from support, through), but IO and performance can be measured and it was measured by me with help from Babin lonston's answer. But I still concerned, that my question about Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS Server will be actual for another rookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk Statics i/O can be monitored using

```
sar -b
```

This will show the CPU static

```
sar
```

This will show the i/o every 5 secs

```
iostat -x 1
```

Diagonis Hight I/O Wait using command

```
sudo iostat

sudo iotop
```

Configure sysstat

edit the file under

```
vim /etc/default/sysstat

ENABLED="false"

to

ENABLED="true"
```

IN VPS u cant check the SMART , i think so , But not confirmed

Im using monit to monitor Our VPS server's